# servlet redirects me to home but blank page

Tags: web-services, jsp, servlets, web-applications, jstl

why does doPost redirects me to the correct page but it shows a blank page?

I have to different jsp file that both have doPost action that's why I have if statements on the main controller. I tried them both but they both redirects me to url/home but it shows blank.

here's the code for the controller

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = req.getParameter("id");
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String mobile = req.getParameter("mobile");

        if(req.getParameter("db")!= null){
        Map<String, Object> record = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ds = new DataService();

        record.put("name", name);
        record.put("email", email);
        record.put("mobile", mobile);

        if (id == null) {
            ds.updateRecord(DataService.INSERT_RECORD, record);
        } else {
            record.put("_id", Integer.parseInt(id));
            ds.updateRecord(DataService.UPDATE_RECORD, record);
        }
        resp.sendRedirect("home");
        }


        else if(req.getParameter("t2s") != null){
        TextToSpeechService service = new TextToSpeechService();
        String text = req.getParameter("name");
        service.getAudio(text, resp);
```

here's the home.jsp file

```
<body>
<h3>Address Book App (Using MySQL)</h3>
<a href="home?action=new">* New Contact</a>
<hr>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${contacts}" var="contact">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${contact.name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${contact.email}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${contact.mobile}" /></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="home?action=edit&id=<c:out value="${contact._id}" />">Edit</a>
                    <a href="home?action=delete&id=<c:out value="${contact._id}" />">Delete</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <form action="home" name="t2s" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" value="Button"/>"></input>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here's the updated xml file base on the answer of @hewittvs

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>Watson - Text to Speech</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/home</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/home.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with JSPs and Servlets, I have faced this blank screen problem and most of the time I made some mistake that caused a runtime exception. See the server logs for checking whether any runtime exception has occurred.

And also maybe in

```
resp.sendRedirect("home");
```

you are specifying **home** instead of **home.jsp**. Make sure you write the appropriate  JSP servlet mapping on that URL pattern to your webapp's web.xml.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/home.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

Comment: i added the url pattern you provided and still it didn't work. I tried looking for runtime error but it doesn't throw any error. I'm currently using bluemix's pipelining to create the website.